# Having issues with VLookup of merge and center values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am having the data where I have shop numbers and street number(merged and centered)

In another sheet, i have shop numbers and I want street number corresponding to it with the help of Vlookup.
But the problem is ..VLookup is giving error values. My formula is :

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,A:D,4,0)
```

I have attached the screenshot.

***Screenshot***

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

***Screenshot 2***

[image]

Comment: You put `A2` as lookup value but your screenshot shows lookup value should `O4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your scenario in Excel and found that using the Index,Match combination will yield the appropriate result. The code used is:

=INDEX($D$5:$D$12,MATCH(H6,$A$5:$A$12,0))

The images below show in Excel

[image]

[image]

The images above show the formulas as they were entered and the result is correct regardless of the merged cells. For future use, the INDEX,MATCH combo can always be used in place of a V-lookup or an H-lookup so you can learn that function to replace both of these others.

Comment: @analyst123456789 : Thankyou for understanding my question and solving my problem :) works like a charm

Comment: @pnuts : please apply some common sense before answering any question.

Comment: Brother, It works fine until there is more than one shop numbers for one street number.
I am attaching new screenshot
You can see that street number is showing 0 if i put shop number as 1219383 but works fine if i put shop number as 293283.
So it is catching only upper value.

sorry i didnt include it earlier, i didnot notice.
if u say, i can open new thread